# Magento 2 - Single Time Picker error on save

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, form-validation

I have already added new form field - time picker.
When I'm trying to save form, post value is overridden on "Invalid date".

```
  <field name="flight_hour" formElement="date" sortOrder="40">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">flight</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="timeOnly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Flight hour</label>
            <dataScope>flight_hour</dataScope>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

This is error in my XML or core bug ?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? i also faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to the `<item>` `option`:

```
<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
```